# Change behavior of citation link when clicked

Tags: org-mode, citation

When I click on a citation like this:

```
cite:Thompson_CalculusMadeEasy2014
```

I get to choose from a list of `citation actions` which include adding notes.

When I follow the link below, it only brings up a buffer that shows the relevant `bibtex` entry.

```
[cite:@Thompson_CalculusMadeEasy2014]
```

Is there any way I could choose to access or notes through the link above?

Comment: What function are you using to open notes?

Comment: I use `helm-bibtex` to search for the relevant reference and press `<F8>` to open notes. Not sure what function `citation actions` calls under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the notes function for the follow property.

```lisp
(org-cite-register-processor 'my-org-cite-follow
  :follow (lambda (datum _arg)
            (bibtex-completion-edit-notes
             (list (org-element-property :key datum)))))

(setq org-cite-follow-processor 'my-org-cite-follow)
```